# Access denied when calling FastEndpoints endpoint when working with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: authentication, endpoint, asp.net-core-6.0, fast-endpoints

I am working on an ASP.NET 6 POC and I am checking if I can migrate to minimal APIs and [FastEndpoints](https://fast-endpoints.com/).

I am interested in using only authentication against an Azure AD tenant and my relevant configuration is as follows:

```cs
services.AddFastEndpoints();

services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration);

services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

services.AddSwaggerDoc(c =>
{
    AddSwaggerDocs_ConfigureAuth(c, auth);
}, addJWTBearerAuth: false);

c.AddAuth("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
    {
        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = $"{auth.Instance}/{auth.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
            TokenUrl = $"{auth.Instance}/{auth.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            Scopes = { { $"api://{auth.ClientId}/access_as_user", "Access as user" } }
        }
    }
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseFastEndpoints();


app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3(c =>
{
    c.ConfigureDefaults();

    c.OAuth2Client = new OAuth2ClientSettings
    {
        ClientId = auth.ClientId,
        AppName = "Foo - Swagger",
        UsePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant = true
    };
});
```

This correctly configures Swagger and I am able to get a token from my Azure AD:

[image: Swagger Docs oauth2 authorization with]

My test endpoint is the following:

```cs
public class GetWeatherEndpoint : Endpoint<GetWeatherInput, List<WeatherForecast>>
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    public override void Configure()
    {
        Get("weather/{days:int}");
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(GetWeatherInput input, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var response = Enumerable.Range(1, input.Days).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToList();

        await SendOkAsync(response, token);
    }
}
```

If I try to call this, I receive a 401, as authorization is enabled by default. If I add `AllowAnonymous()`, it works as expected (`HandleAsync` gets called).

When working with controllers, a simple `Authorized` attribute would make things work.

Any idea about how to properly configure the endpoint in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is most likely a minor misconfiguration.

in order to see why exactly the auth middleware is sending a 401 response, you'd have to do something similar to what's being done in [this article](https://referbruv.com/blog/building-custom-responses-for-unauthorized-requests-in-aspnet-core/) to log the reason.

basically you need to tap in to a hook like `OnAuthenticationFailed` and log the reason for failure.

it seems the request is not reaching fastendpoints due to the auth middleware interrupting the flow earlier on.

maybe try the `subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents` in [AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebapiservicecollectionextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapiauthentication?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-identity-web-microsoftidentitywebapiservicecollectionextensions-addmicrosoftidentitywebapiauthentication(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration-system-string-system-string-system-boolean))

also don't you need a `app.UseAuthentication()` call with azure ad?

Comment: +1. `app.UseAuthentication()` was commented out by mistake and that was the cause for not working. I have also learned something new about seeing authentication failed context.